# Updating Excel sheet when we save data in document library

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2010, updates

User did download the excel countries data from folders in the one SharePoint library Using “export to excel”. And also he store the Macro-enabled excel workbook.

1- When we save data in document library, we can get the data and call excel service REST API to write the data to the excel sheet. How to achive this ?

2- Is that possible, when running Macro's in Excel Workbooks stored in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on 'Export to Excel', click anywhere on the data in the excel.
Then a tab will be highlighted in the Excel ribbon named 'Design'.
When you do changes in Doc library, just refresh it on the excel by clicking on the 'Refresh' button under 'Design' tab. Thats it.

You can even disconnect excel with SharePoint by clicking on 'Unlink' under 'Design' tab.
You can also export this excel to new SharePoint list by clicking on 'Export' under 'Design' tab.

Hope this helps.
[image]